# How do I refresh page automatically when partial refresh doesn't work?

Tags: xpages

If a leave a xpage open in the browser for a couple of hours, then when I come back and try to click on the pager (which does a partial refresh), it doesn't work. So how can I automatically detect this and force a full refresh? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on what you are trying to accomplish, and what you are willing to trade off to do it. The reason the partial refresh fails is because the user's XSP session has timed out, so the information about the particular user's page view has expired, and can not be just "made to work." What has to happen is you'll need to either devise and implement a way to maintain and reload the state of the page, which then has to be restored inside a new session, or the session needs to never expire in the first place. The second way is the easiest, and the first is very difficult. There is a setting on the XPages tab of the application settings that allows you to control the application's timeout. Set the value higher to allow the page to stay active longer. There is a trade off here for as the longer a session is in memory, the more memory that is required, which leads to reduced scalability. Alternatively you can build some some logic into the onError which would detect the failed partial refresh and then perform a full refresh to re-establish the session, but any session data would be lost.

Comment: Hi Jeremy - do you have any example of the first option at all? I was hoping to avoid the second option.

Comment: Jeremy what events are triggered when partial refresh fails or shall I just go with keepSessionAlive ExtLib option as Frantisek mentioned?

Comment: I dont think it will throw an error ... bet bet would be onError of the partial refresh, but i think when the session expires that doesn't happen, it just returns an empty result

Comment: So shall I go down the route of xe:keepSessionAlive as Frantisek and Declan pointed out below?

Comment: If you want it to hold it open indefinitely, yes.  If you want to have it just be open longer - set the application's individual time-out to a longer period.

Answer (score 2):

Look for xe:keepSessionAlive control in ExtLib. It will ping server periodically, so will keep your session alive.

Beware of performance problems in case of too many users keeping their browsers open.

Comment: Thanks Frantisek for your comments, I saw this in Matt Whites xpages101 sessions, I will have to look at the video again, is it possible to tell this thing to only ping it for 1 day max?

Comment: The xe:keepSessionAlice works in conjunction with the sessionTimeout value in the application to work out an optimal ping interval.