# inputText onchange event not called after inactivity

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a typeahead enabled on an inputText field which triggers an onChange event.  This works fine unless the page has not been refreshed for a period of time (in testing, it stops working after 1 hour but may be less).  Refreshing the page completely fixes the issue.

The code for the inputText field is as follows;

```
<xp:inputText id="quickSelectEntry" style="width:170px;">
    <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="placeHolder" value="Enter name">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
    <xp:typeAhead mode="none" minChars="2" ignoreCase="true"
        var="searchValue" valueMarkup="true">
        <xp:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:return         nameTypeAhead(searchValue)}]]></xp:this.valueList>
                </xp:typeAhead>

                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="norefresh">
                    <xp:this.action>
                        <xp:actionGroup>
                            <xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var searchVal:string = getComponent("quickSelectEntry").getValue();
if (searchVal.substr(0,1).equals("?")) {
    context.redirectToPage("xCheckSecurityGroup.xsp?group=" + searchVal.substr(1));
    return false;
} else {
    var doc:NotesDocument = quickLookupView.getDocumentByKey(searchVal, true);
    if (null != doc) {
        viewScope.lookupKey = doc.getUniversalID();
        viewScope.lookupForm = doc.getItemValueString("form");
        return true;
    } else {
        viewScope.lookupKey = ""
        viewScope.lookupForm = ""
        return false;
    }
}
]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:executeScript>
                            <xp:actionGroup>
                                <xp:this.condition><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.lookupKey != ""}]]></xp:this.condition>

                                <xp:openPage target="openDocument"
                                    documentId="#{javascript:return viewScope.lookupKey}">
                                    <xp:this.name><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "x" + viewScope.lookupForm + ".xsp" }]]></xp:this.name>
                                </xp:openPage>
                            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:actionGroup>
    </xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

So far I've tried doing a timed partial refresh of the containing panel with no joy, I've set the typeahead mode from none to full.  No difference.

Aside from refreshing the page every 10 minutes, is there anything else that couple be causing the problem.  FYI The actual typeahead is working correctly consistently, its just the onchange event that stops firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May want to check the Application Properties(go to Xpages tab).  There you can set the Application and the session timeouts for the database.  If these are blank I think they will default to server which is typically 30 minutes.

V/R,

Kev

Comment: If I don't get the keepSessionAlive working then this will be the next option combined with a forced refresh as described by Howard below.

Answer (score 2):

What seems to happen is that the server web session is intact but the XPages session is lost.

Add the following to the bottom of your XPage and what it will do is refresh the DIV preiodically based on your setting (in milliseconds) (300000 = 300 seconds = 5 minutes) - the longest I have had a successful test is 3.5 hours.

You need to set a value at least one minute less than the session timeout length set in the application properties for your database.

```
<xp:div id="keepSessionAlive"></xp:div>
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value>
    <![CDATA[   
        XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:keepSessionAlive}", {});   
            }, 300000)
        })]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Do not set a short refresh time as this will needlessly waste bandwidth and also bloat IE's RAM usage which is not well managed by the browser.

Understand that this is a SECURITY ISSUE at the same time - by basically keeping an idle computer's session alive you leave it open to hijack without the user's knowledge - that is the part of the point of a timeout

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the XSP session times out (according to your server settings). See this answer for recommendations on keeping the session alive:
[How do I refresh page automatically when partial refresh doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557814/how-do-i-refresh-page-automatically-when-partial-refresh-doesnt-work)

Comment: We use ExtLib keepSessionAlive control in every page, but it didn't help - pages do not work after some idle time, even though in domlog there are many successful pings from that page...

Comment: This may indeed be a bug with the runtime - I will look into the use case above and escalate it if necessary

Comment: Thanks @PaulHannan, contact me if you need more details. It really bothers our users.

Comment: Hi @FrantisekKossuth how do I contact you for more details?

Comment: I already have a keepSessionAlive control in a custom control which is used by every page in my app.  I will add the keepSessionAlive directly in the control where the timeout is occuring and see if it helps for it be more local.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this too. I ended up putting in a meta refresh tag to reload the page every 30 minutes. It was the only thing that seems to work.

Howard

Comment: Any side effects? What I think is problem with this solution: idle form in edit mode - user loses unsaved data after redirect. Am I wrong?

Comment: Doesn't seem to, the values are still bound to the controls.  You can try it at http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/DeveloperView.xsp

Comment: How do you bind those controls on the left? Their values seem to be persistent even in new tab, so that is not standard situation. I mean, if you redirect your page (GET, not POST) you will loose your bindings to datasource, I believe.

Comment: This will be my next option combined with the application timeout.